# Parallax Story Telling Website. How to get Started

Tags: scroll, parallax, portfolio, parallax.js

I want to create a Parallax Story Telling Website, for my portfolio. I have a good hand on HTML CSS3 and JAVASCRIPT. I just want some advice on how to start up with this project, which plugins to use etc... im new to parallax.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library, it's very simple and the demo page is very cool! :)

https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax